# Programa adivinador de numero Python

Tags: python, condiciones, variables, bucles, print

Voy empezando y estoy intentando hacer un codigo que genere un numero aleatorio y el usuario tenga que adivinar que numero es. El usuario tiene 3 intentos para hacerlo, si acierta el programa lo felicita y si no le dice cual era el numero aleatorio. Al final del juego el programa le pregunta si quiere jugar de nuevo y depende de la respuesta del usuario empieza de nuevo el juego o no. Esto es lo que tengo (de alguna u otra forma algo falla siempre):

```
import random

name = input("Hey! What's your name? ")
print(f"OK {name} let's have a little game.")

wanna_play = "yes"

while wanna_play.lower() == "yes":
    num = random.randint(1, 10)
    num_guess = int(input("Guess the number I'm thinking of: "))
    attempts = 0
    while num != num_guess and attempts < 2:
        num_guess = input("Try again! Guess the number I'm thinking of: ")
        attempts += 1
    if num == num_guess:
        print("Congrats that's the correct number!")
    else:
        print(f"Out of attempts! You lose, the correct number was: {str(num)}")
    wanna_play = input("Do you wanna play again? ")

print("OK, goodbye!")
```

Comment: El programa funciona correctamente. ¿Qué falla encuentras?

Comment: Si el usuario acierta, el programa sigue diciendo: "Try again! Guess the number I'm thinking of: ", y cuando te dice cual era el numero correcto resulta que en alguno de los intentos habia acertado

Comment: Claro, como nunca le acerte al numerito no me percate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea

```
    num_guess = input("Try again! Guess the number I'm thinking of: ")
```

te olvidaste de aplicar `int()`, por lo que ahora `num_guess` es una cadena, y las cadenas no son iguales a los enteros.

Solución:

```
    num_guess = int(input("Try again! Guess the number I'm thinking of: "))
```

Comment: Claro, muchas gracias! No me di cuenta